# I created My angular project in Angular v8.1.3 , I want to run all the above angular version

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

I am trying to update my Angular app from v5 to v6 following.
I have ran all these commands successfully:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli
```

The problem is that I get an error when running this command:

ng update @angular/core

```
  Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0" (extended), would install "15.0.1").
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler-cli" (requires "^8.0.0-beta.0 || ^8.1.0-beta.0 || ^8.2.0-beta.0 || ^8.3.0-beta.0 || ^8.4.0-beta.0 || >=9.0.0-beta < 9" (extended), would install "15.0.1").
                  Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires ">=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0" (extended), would install "15.0.1").
                  Package "@angular/material" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/animations" (requires "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0" (extended), would install "15.0.1").
                  Package "@angular/material" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0" (extended), would install "15.0.1").
                  Package "ngx-toastr" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires ">=6.0.0 <9.0.0" (extended), would install "15.0.1").
                  Package "@angular/cdk" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0" (extended), would install "15.0.1").
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=3.1 < 3.5", would install "4.8.4").
                  Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^6.3.0", would install "7.5.7").
Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
```

I am not sure how to handle this & I don't want to try things on my own to avoid breaking the app.

Can someone please advise what to do?

My current dependencies are as follows:

Answer (score 0):

You should not wait so long before updating otherwise it gets difficult to upgrade. Angular v15 is already out so you should have at least Angular v13 by now. I suggest you always update to the latest version when the version is available.

You can follow the following documentation. You will have to update each version 1 by 1. i.e. Update from 5 to 6, then from 6 to 7, etc.

https://update.angular.io/?v=5.0-6.0